# Hibernate Session Is Closed - help creating method

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I was trying to create object class with hibernate sql methods such as adding new record, getting data from database etc. Everything is working fine, but only ONCE. When I try to call the same method again I get 'Session is closed' error. Here's code of selecting one record method:

```
public static Event getSqlRecord(int id) {
    SessionFactory session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory();
    Session sess = session.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();


    Event ev = new Event();
    try {
        Query query = sess.createQuery("from Event where idWydarzenia = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        ev = (Event)query.uniqueResult();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    session.close();

    return ev;
}
```

About HibernateSessionFactory, here's class body:

```
package pl.objects;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateSessionFactory {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Blad inicjalizacji SessionFactory" + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

I was using the example i found in some tutorial. How can i make this method do open session, do stuff and then close it?

Comment: Using `getCurrentSession()`, the SF creates a `session` and pins it to a "current" context (in your case probably a thread). You shouldn't close a session obtained via `getCurrentSession()`, only via `openSession()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not required to close the session when using the sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

The context/transaction will take care of closing it for you.